# Навигация. Не работает ссылка.

Tags: php

Имеется код:

```
<h1 align='center'><a  href='http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].@dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])."/'>Вход на сайт</a></h1>
```

Когда наводишь на ссылку появляется адрес:

```
http://site.ru\/
```

и естественно ссылка не работает. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<h1 align='center'><a  href='http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].@dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])."/'>Вход на сайт</a></h1>
```

Ну `@dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])` зачем? Задача то какая ставится? Сделать ссылку на сайт или как?

**//upd**

Может, у тебя есть страница для входа на сайт, так пропиши её в ссылке:

```
<a  href='http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/login'>Вход на сайт</a>
```

`dirname` открывает директорию на серваке, оно то тебе зачем?

Comment: Да. Так оно и было. Была явная ссылка на сайт. Проблема возникла когда начал перемещать фалы страниц в другие директории. Появилась необходимость в глобальных переменных. Пытаюсь разобраться с навигацией. Сколько не читал про глобальные переменные - ничего не понял. Этот код нашел в инете в файле формирующий ошибку 404. Вставил его в свой файл, и оказалось, что не работает.
Вопросов то много, но не буду же я все задавать - вот и пытаюсь понять на одном примере.

Comment: Почему появляется не нужный слеш в адресе?
Грубо говоря, если эта переменная глобальная и нигде не задается - почему не работает как должна?
Извините, может вопрос глупый...)))

Comment: `@dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])` - это не нужно тебе. Это и ставит тебе слеш в конце.

Comment: Он должен ставить слеш в конце, а перед ним обратный слеш не должен быть. Из-за него ссылка и не работает.
Возможно, и не нужно - есть много способов обойти это, просто хотел понять причину. На других сайтах то зачем-то прописывают `dirname`.

Comment: @dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) тут в добавок передается параметр, а тебе оно не нужно, просто сам ставь слеш и все. Я вообще такое впервые вижу.